# PHP error: Undefined property: stdClass::$access_token when property_exists says true

Tags: php

I am getting the following error in an authentication callback using PHP5:

```php
Undefined property: stdClass::$access_token
```

Here is the code:

```php
$result = curl_exec($ch);
$data = json_decode($result);


var_dump(property_exists($data, 'access_token'));
var_dump($data);
var_dump($data->access_token);

$token = $data->access_token;
```

and here is the result of that code:

```php
bool(true) 
object(stdClass)#1 (5) { ["access_token"]=> string(36) "pretend-code-is-here" ["token_type"]=> string(6) "bearer" ["expires_in"]=> int(3600) ["refresh_token"]=> string(36) "pretend-code-is-here" ["scope"]=> string(8) "identity" } 
string(36) "pretend-code-is-here"
```

The code matches the specific var_dump but I cannot assign it to $token without getting that error and I cannot use it in following requests.

Comment: Your code works fine. Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/01de56325e542e9abdb960daed2e7eef6d36945a . Can't reproduce the error. Either you've got the wrong end of the stick somewhere, or there's something else you're not telling us. Please provide us with enough information about your scenario to actually reproduce the issue, otherwise we're unlikely to be able to diagnose the cause. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure if it is relevant, but running on php-fpm through nginix. There is also a bit after the error's path that says "while reading response header from upstream"

Comment: Can you post the whole message in full, so it's 100% clear?